# Ruby DevKit in cygwin not working

Tags: ruby, gcc, sqlite, makefile, cygwin

Im trying to install gems that require the ruby DevKit to be installed. E.g:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

This is the output:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_next_stmt()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-cygwin -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE
_RB_PROC_ARITY -DHAVE_SQLITE3_INITIALIZE -DHAVE_SQLITE3_NEXT_STMT -DHAVE_SQLITE3_BACKUP_INIT -DHAVE_SQLITE3_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION -DHAVE_SQL
ITE3_LOAD_EXTENSION -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/local/include -I/usr/include    -O3 -g -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-
parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long  -o backup.o -c backup.c
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [backup.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

I do have make and gcc installed and don't understand why it's complaining that a command can't be found.

This happens not only if i try to install the sqlite3 gem but also other gems that require de devkit to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevKit is for the MingW port of YARV, not the Cygwin port. The Cygwin port doesn't need the DevKit, since Cygwin itself already contains all the necessary tools, libraries, and headers.